# Exchange 2007 - relay mail for one address to another server

Tags: email, exchange-2007, mailing-list, phplist

I'm putting in a list server to manage all the marketing mailshots that we send out.  The solution I'm using ([PHPList](http://www.phplist.com/)) has some nice functionality for handling bounces, but I need to get the bounces to get to the server first.  The list server sends out through our ISP's smart host, but using our main domain name in the "from" field for the list emails.

The problem is, mail **to** that domain goes to our Exchange server; I therefore need some way of grabbing email to that address and getting it to go to the list server rather than the Exchange server.  This doesn't seem to be possible using only Hub Transport rules, so does anyone know how I might accomplish this?  Or am I going about it in entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mail will always end up at your Exchange server, and because it believes itself to be responsible for all mail delivered to that domain, will attempt to deliver it locally if the account exists, and bounce it if not.

There are a couple of options here:

- Setup another email address for the list server, not on your domain, forward email from the mailbox on the Exchange server to this address
- Send email from a sub domain, e.g. mail@list.domain.com, set up the MX record for list.domain.com to point to the list server.

Comment: I thought the answer would be something like that, but thanks for confirming.  Think I'll go for the subdomain.